# How do I write a spell for mermaids?

Tags: merfolk, music, magic

I am writing a world in which humanoids are turned into merpeople via a song-spell. Any ideas on how do write one? I would like it to be in a different language, maybe a mix of Tolkien Elvish, Latin, and Spanish. Are there key words for transformation spells? The spell is supposed to bring out the person's spirit and use their personality to determine their traits/abilities. Thank you!

Comment: It's your world. What are the rules for magic in your world?

Comment: Hi Sparrow, and very welcome to Worldbuilding and Stack Exchange. Please note that we focus on questions that can be answered objectively, and to which answers can be judged objectively on how well they answer the question. I don't see how at all this question, as it currently stands, would be possible to answer objectively, so I'm putting it on hold until we work out the quirks. For magic questions, you need to describe the magic system of your world and its rules, or the answer becomes simply "do whatever you want", which is something we very much try to avoid.

Comment: I do encourage you to review [How to deal with “I have a High Concept, please do my work for me” questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/29) and [How to write the perfect question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624/29), both on [meta], after which you can [Edit] your question. If you edit during the "on hold" grace period, your question will automatically be nominated for reopen review by the community. You may also want to take the quick site [Tour] and review the "asking" section of our [Help].

Comment: Last, please understand that putting questions on hold is not a slight against you, but merely our mechanism for ensuring that people don't spend time answering the wrong question. Hopefully, with some editing, this question will be possible to reopen and the community will be able to provide *good answers,* as opposed to simply their own favorite opinions.

Comment: If it's just the language that's a problem, try an online conlang generator.  Here's one:  https://www.vulgarlang.com/  It has a free and a $10 version.  For the content, look up "kennings" and try this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_magic  .  If you take your best shot then you can detail what you have and edit the question asking for feasibility.